# Resltet does not return url params from post request

Tags: java, tomcat7, tomcat6, restlet

I have a [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) request:

```
https://localhost/rest/myAPI/1.0/myStatusUpdate?usr=me&pwd=secret
```

My Request headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 67
```

I use `resltet` 1.1. (This version of resltet already here for several years on that project. And was not been changed yet)

Before, this line of code returned me query parameters in url:

```
requestBodyParams = request.getEntityAsForm()
urlParams = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm()
```

requestBodyParams.size() = 0 IF urlParams.size() > 0

I.e. I can Not get **ANY** params from RequestBody if I have **SOME** params passing in URL.

Even if I have some params in Request body,  `request.getEntityAsForm()` returns me emptiness if there are some params in url..

I wonder why? Before it worked.

It might be related to Tomcat (before it was `Tomcat6`, now I use `Tomcat7`)

---

Another words: Now I have to follow this rule:

> 1. put **everything** to **url params** and not to use **request body** (request body will be empty)
> 2. put **everything** to **request body** and not to use **url params**

Comment: In production, you're not *actually* putting the password in `$_POST`, right?

Comment: but this is over https and using post. so, I do.